# Android studio / Gradle build fails in release: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:crashlyticsStoreDeobsRelease'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

The build fails only in release, debug builds fine.
Android studio 1.4, Gradle 2.8 RC1, Gradle plugin 1.4.0 BETA 4

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:crashlyticsStoreDeobsRelease'.
...
Error:org.gradle.api.UnknownTaskException: Task with path 'dexRelease' not found in project ':app'.
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is due to the changes made to Gradle 1.4.0.beta2

You need to update the fabric Gradle plugin to a version > 1.20.0:

`classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.20.1'` should do it